# IBM Liberty SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE

Tags: web-services, ssl, websphere-liberty

I am using **Liberty 16.0.0.4**

I am trying to call xxxx SOAP services, but i got the following errors

> [ERROR   ] CWPKI0022E: **SSL HANDSHAKE FAILURE:  A signer with SubjectDN CN=xxxx,  was sent from the target host.  The signer might need to be added to local trust store** serverHome/resources/security/key.jks, located in SSL configuration alias defaultSSLConfig.  The extended error message from the SSL handshake exception is: **PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

I used next command to generate certificate

```
openssl s_client -connect xxxxURL:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > xxx.cert
```

Then injecting it into liberty jks default file with next command

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias xxxSigner -file xxx.cert -keystore *pathToHomeServer/resources/security/key.jks* -storepass Liberty -storetype jks
```

Also this is my server.xml tags related to that

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxb-2.2</feature>
    <feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
    <feature>javaMail-1.5</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
    <feature>apiDiscovery-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" location="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/key.jks" password="{xor}EzY9Oi0rJg==" type="jks" />
<keyStore id="defaultTrustStore" location="${server.config.dir}/resources/security/key.jks" password="{xor}EzY9Oi0rJg==" type="jks" />

<sslDefault sslRef="defaultSSLConfig" />

<ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore" trustStoreRef="defaultTrustStore" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"/>

<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443">
    <sslOptions sslRef="defaultSSLConfig"></sslOptions>
</httpEndpoint>
```

So what is the problem my side which

Comment: Not sure why your approach is not working, but another way to go about it is to use a browser to retrieve the certificate and then keytool to add it, as described here  (see the 8/5/2015 comment at the bottom of the article): https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/single-sign-google-liberty/

Comment: @BruceT. Thanks, Actually it's working when downloaded certificate from WSDL path and inject it using "keytool -import ..." but i don't know what is the wrong when executing it by command using "openssl s_client ...", anyway u can add your answer and i will accept it, Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why your approach is not working, but another way to go about it is to use a browser to retrieve the certificate and then keytool to add it, as described here (see the 8/5/2015 comment at the bottom of the article): developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/single-sign-google-liberty

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you explicitly add the signer itself, shown at the bottom of the stack of certs when you append -showcerts to your openssl command?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working too, i used -showcerts as u suggested so my command is "openssl s_client -showcerts -connect xxx:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > xxx.cert", and it generated the certificate file then injected it into default server jsk file but same exception thrown from Liberty as before :(

Comment: The point was more to stop using the command and copy/paste the root CA  and root CA alone?   

also, https://github.com/covener/plugin-tools/blob/master/retrievesigner.jar